# Donsker for randomly stopped processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

A question regarding Donsker's invariance principle. Donsker states that if $X_1, X_2, ...$ are independent and identically distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and if $S_t^n$ is the interpolated and scaled sum of $X_i$ then $(S_t^n)$ converges in $C$ (room of continuous functions) in distribution  to the Brownian Motion $B$.

My question concerns a randomly stopped version of $S_t^n$. Let $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ now be i.i.d and nonnegative with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. 
Let $N_t:=\max{(m \in \mathcal{N} | S_m < t)}$ (with $S_m$ as the unscaled sum of the $Y_i$) and $D_t^n:= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{N_{nt}}} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_{nt}}(Y_i-\mu)$ + interpolation term.
Does $D_t^n \rightarrow B$ hold in $C$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: But $N_t=+\infty$ for every $t$, no?

Comment: No, $N_t$ is the related counting process and thus we have $N_t < \infty$.

Comment: Not with your definition: if the $X_i$ are i.i.d., square integrable and centered, then $S_m\lt t$ for infinitely many $m$ hence the maximum defining $N_t$ is actually a supremum and $N_t$ is $+\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: You're right. I've improved the explanation and distinguished between $X_i$ and some nonnegative random variables $Y_i$.